# Condition in SQLite trigger for inheritance

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, single-table-inheritance

I'm working with `SQLite`,I am using XOR single table inheritance, I want to create a trigger that enables me to:

1. Check before insertion if the `InstructionRefs.id` is already created in the table `RideHeightRefs`
2. Ckeck before insertion that the `InstructionRefs.id` does not exist in the other inherited table `StrappingRefs`.
   [image]
   I took some oracle PL/SQL code and changed it, I guess I am writing it wrong starting from `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id...)`:

   `CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_instructionRefs_trigger BEFORE INSERT     ON InstructionRefs

   BEGIN

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM RideHeightRefs AS RHR INNER JOIN InstructionRefs 
   IR ON RHR.id = IR.id)

       BEGIN

           SELECT RAISE(FAIL, '"RideHeightRefs" key is unknown. Insertion in 
           "instructionRefs" is impossible.')

       END'

       IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM   (SELECT RideHeightRefs
               FROM StrappingRefs
               UNION ALL
               SELECT RideHeightRefs
               FROM InstructionRefs) T
               WHERE RideHeightRefs IN (SELECT RideHeightRefs
               FROM NEW))
       BEGIN
              SELECT RAISE(FAIL, '"RideHeightRefs" key is used in another table. Insertion in "StrappingRefs" is impossible.') 
       END
   END`

How can I modify the code to make it compatible with sqlite syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the corresponding row in the base table exists, just use a [foreign key constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

SQLite has no IF statement. To check for something, add a WHERE clause to the SELECT FAIL, or use the trigger's WHEN clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_instructionRefs_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON InstructionRefs
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM StrappingRefs
             WHERE id = NEW.id)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(FAIL, '"RideHeightRefs" key is used in another table. Insertion in "StrappingRefs" is impossible.');
END;
```

Comment: You mean To check if the corresponding row in the other inherited table exists. This actually seems a much simple and clean code.. And the same is applied on the base table right ?

Comment: As I said, for the base table, you can use a foreign key constraint.

Comment: I created a trigger in SQLiteStudio and wrote your code, but there is a problem in the condition (underlined in red): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QRxxlyn92wLpofFwG6Ofk6qsDN8YPRsp

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.